# How to display a dynamic table

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

Am finding it very difficult to display a dynamic table from a database. Please i need help.

I want my table to look like the picture below.

[image]

But i keep having it like the picture below

[image]

From the above picture, the text box input is not appearing on the other two column

Below is my database table am displaying the data from.

[image]

[image]

Below is my code used to display my dynamic table, but is not giving me what i wanted. Please i need help.

```
type here
$query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `asign_subject`,student,class WHERE asch_id = '$session_id' 
                                    AND asign_subject.asubclas_id=student.stuclas_id
                                    AND student.stuclas_id=class.class_id
                                    AND `asubclas_id`='$asubclas_id' 
                                    AND `asubj_id`='$asubj_id' 
                                    AND `asec_id`='$asec_id'") or die(mysqli_error());
                                    
                            
        while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $db_name=$fetch['name'];
            $db_stu_id=$fetch['stu_id'];
            $db_regno=$fetch['reg_no'];
            $db_class=$fetch['asubclas_id'];
            $db_subject=$fetch['asubj_id'];
            $db_sec=$fetch['asec_id'];
            $db_sch=$fetch['asch_id'];
            $db_teacher=$fetch['atech_id'];
            $db_id=$fetch['asigsub_id'];
            $db_sect=$fetch['classect_id'];
            
            
        
        echo "<form method='POST' action=''>";
        echo " 
        
        <form method='post' action='' id='add-exam-scores'>
        
            <tr>
            <input type='hidden' sl' name='slno[]' id='slno' value='1' readonly=''>
            <td>$db_regno</td>
            <td>$db_name</td>
            <td><input type='number' name='ass_1[]' placeholder='1st CA' class='form-control' value=''></td>
            <td><input type='number' name='ass_2[]' placeholder='2nd CA' class='form-control' value=''></td>
            <td><input type='number' name='exam[]' placeholder='Exam' class='form-control' max='60.0' min='0' step='0.01' value=''></td>
            <input type='hidden' name='scostu_id[]' value='$db_stu_id'>
            <input type='hidden' name='scoclas_id[]' value='$db_class'>
            <input type='hidden' name='scosbj_id[]' value='$db_subject'>
            <input type='hidden' name='scosec_id[]' value='$db_sec'>
            <input type='hidden' name='schsco_id[]' value='$db_sch'>
            <input type='hidden' name='scotech_id[]' value='$db_teacher'>
            <input type='hidden' name='asign_id[]' value='$db_id'>
            <input type='hidden' name='scoset_id[]' value='$db_sect'>
                     
            </tr>
        
        ";
    }
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: The above HTML suggests you have nested `FORM` elements. In addition to that your HTML is further mangled by the incorrect nesting of the `TR` and contents within previously mentioned nested form. The `hidden` input elements are also located at an invalid location in the HTML structure - they should be within a table-cell **not** simply added within the table-row as they are.

Comment: What is `<input type='hidden' sl'...` ? That random stray `sl'` within that input tag is not correct

Answer (score 2):

This is not a PHP issue.  It is an HTML issue.  You are only echoing/printing out five td tags/columns.  You need seven td to generate your desired output in the picture.

You basically need to add something like this

```
<td><input type="text"/></td>
<td><input type="text"/></td>
```